# What does the 'A' in ACodec.cpp mean in Android's libstagefright?

Tags: android, media, android-source, codec

What does the 'A' in ACodec.cpp mean in Android's libstagefright?

Full path is below:

```
android/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp
```

Please explain answer and background knowledge.

Source link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/437ced8a14944bf5450df50c5e7e7a6dfe20ea40/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding, the `A` in `ACodec` stands for asynchronous. I believe this is based on the implementation / design of the overall codec functionality.

In case of `ACodec`, all operations are handled through `messages` posted from a different thread. When the message is received, `onMessageReceived` method will be scheduled which will then process the `event`. This way almost all operations in this implementation is asynchronous and hence, the name.

For example, the procedure to setup is through the messages as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#3008).In `onSetup`, the component instance is [created](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#onAllocateComponent) and [configured](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#onConfigureComponent).

The similar set of operations in case of `OMXCodec` are synchronous in nature as found in [`OMXCodec::create`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#275). Typically, `OMXCodec::create` is called as part of [`AwesomePlayer::initVideoDecoder`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp#1489) or [`AwesomePlayer::initAudioDecoder`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp#1381), in which cases the call to `OMXCodec` is a synchronous one.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know precisely, but it seems to me that 'A' means abstract. I think that this is a class that realize logic for working with different codecs not specifying a precise codec type.

Comment: someone says the 'A' means async. i'm not sure but what do you think?

Comment: It may also mean Audio ) We can only guess here )